# Python - Flask - Redis - ResponseError: unknown command 'SETEX'

Tags: python, session, redis, debian, flask

I'm trying to create server-side sessions using Redis through Flask. Redis-server appears to be running fine, but Flask keeps giving me this error when implementing the [example class on Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/).

```
ResponseError: unknown command 'SETEX'
```

...as such, my Flask project does not run.

**Edit:**

I am running:

- Redis 2.4.15
- Python 2.7.3 (and 2.6 in virtualenv)

Comment: What version of Redis are you using?

Comment: okay, that was a long shot that you were using Redis < 2.0..

Comment: I'm new to Redis, so I've only had about an hour using it. I wish it were that simple :P. Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/2011bff122e3daad) . Maybe you are getting wrong version number.

Comment: Wow, spot on! I'm running Version: 2:1.2.6-1 (1.2.6). Do you know how I could go about upgrading? When I run redis-cli, it opens version 2.4.6.

Comment: @user1492385 I do not use debian, so don't know how to upgrade in it.

Comment: Oops, I deleted the comment saying I fixed it. I have fixed it now, thanks for pointing out what the issue was :).